# how can i fetch optional_customization from this data in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, mongoose

{
"_id":{
"$oid":"604b263c3cbb802128f9fa69"
},
"payment_type":"COD",
"status":"order_placed",
"customerId":{
"$oid":"6043582dc4a9ff1908b9023a"
},
"product":{
"_id":"5ff8a16558594812f86d3aa2",
"title":"tuck end auto bottom box",
"subname":"bottom pasting",
"category":"folded carton",
"unicode":"ptt:fc002",
"description":"",
"job_name":"dummy orderr",
"lenght":"420",
"height":"6",
"width":"6",
"printing_type":"mattellic",
"paper_board":"fbb white back grey back",
"gsm":"400",
"cmyk":"cmyk",
"pms_color":"1",
"coating":[
"lamination",
"Uv-drip off",
"full uv gloss",
"matte"
],
"quantity":"85210",
"optional_customization":[
"foil_stamping",
"dembossing"
],
"optional_finishing_packaging":[
"four_fold",
"regular"
],
"designs":[
{

```
     }
  ],
  "quote_id":"05f53caf-4ffb-4898-8cf9-ea0f3f763d15"
```

},
"phone":"4551621619190",
"address":"tulsi nagar",
"couponCode":"jfau",
"createdAt":{
"$date":"2021-03-12T08:28:44.693Z"
},
"updatedAt":{
"$date":"2021-03-12T08:28:44.693Z"
},
"__v":0
}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onLzt.png)

Comment: Have you spend a single minute reading about how to interact with JSON? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Answer (score 0):

let payload = {YourJSON}

let taget = payload.product.optional_customization

use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# for user friendly format is needed